# Как достать число из переменной?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно извлечь число из класса у элемента для дальнейшей работы с ним.
Класс извлек, но почему число то не извлекается, почему parseInt не выполняет задачу?

```js
class_cal = $('#cal-view-2').attr('class').split(' ')[0];
console.log(class_cal);
console.log(parseInt(class_cal));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cal-view-2" class="cal-6 cal clearfix Drupal-availabilityCalendar-View-init-processed">
  <div>
```

Comment: Потому что это не его работа

Comment: если нужно извлекать по шаблону, нужно использовать регексы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно выделить число из строки:

- регулярным выражением: `.match(/\d+/)[0]`
- разделением в массив: `.split('-')[1]`
- любым другим способом

```js
class_cal = $('#cal-view-2').attr('class').split(' ')[0];
console.log(class_cal);
console.log(parseInt(class_cal.match(/\d+/)[0]));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cal-view-2" class="cal-6 cal clearfix Drupal-availabilityCalendar-View-init-processed">
  <div>
```

Comment: плохо /\d+/. Если там будут какие-нибудь другие паттерны?

Comment: плюс [0] возвращает полную строку. Первая капч группа с 1 начинается

Comment: @Herrgott, товарищ, будьте внимательнее. Анализируется конкретный класс, полученный автором вопроса. И в рег.выражении нет ни одной группы захвата

Comment: то есть раз у него класс на первом месте, то нужно делать split[0]? Не совсем ли уж голимый подход? А если кто-то добавит первым классом col-md-2?

Comment: Получение нужной строки вне компетенции ответа на вопрос "как достать число из переменной". Авторский код - он так видит.

Comment: я понимаю что вне компетенций. Но если отвечать прям топорно, то через 5 минут появится вопрос "Почему #743498 неправильно работает, возвращается другое число?", а потом еще один топорный ответ и снова череда через чур глупых вопросов. Мы ж тут как-бы помогаем, а не просто чтобы отвязались

Comment: Мы тут не помогаем, а создаём базу знаний. Нерелевантные ответы не нужны. Ничего плохого в дополнительном вопросе я не вижу.

Comment: И, вы полагаете, что ваш ответ менее "топорен"?

Comment: я его дополнил только что

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего не полагаться на то, что класс, из которого выделяется число будет первым в массиве ([0]), а получить всю строку классов (document.getElementById('id').classList.value) и выделить число по шаблону `/(?:^|\s+)cal-view-(\d+)(?:\s+|$)/`. Это гарантирует что выделяемое число не будет числом другого класса

```
const match = /(?:^|\s+)cal-view-(\d+)(?:\s+|$)/.exec(class_cal)
console.log(parseInt(match[1]))
```

Comment: Тогда уж `/(?:^|\s+)cal-view-(\d+)(?:\s+|$)/`

Comment: @vp_arth зачем?

Comment: А вдруг там будет класс `bcal-view-7`? Или `cal-view-2-old`?

Comment: логично конечно

Comment: @Herrgott в моем случае не будет)) цифра всегда в конце класса и имеет уникальное значение